# Overriding generic abstract method to return specific type

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract class that is the below method signature:

`protected abstract TResponse Handle<TResponse>(T command)`

In a class that overrides this I have something like the below:

```
protected override TResponse Handle<TResponse>(ListFilmsByIdCommand command)
{
    return 9;
}
```

However this fails to compile as it cannot convert int to TResponse.  If I change `TResponse` to `int` or some other `DTO` type class it also fails.

Is there a way to have the abstract method and override it so I can return any type I want?

Comment: I don't think you can override it with a different return type. Your best bet seems to be to return object type rather than TResponse.

Comment: Your method uses generics, so the caller can define the type that is returned. If the caller does var x = Handle<int>(command) then it makes sense for you to return an int. But what if the caller does var x = Handle<List<string>>(command) ? Then you should return a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override `TResponse Handle<TResponse>` with an implementation returning anything except `TResponse`, because this is the type the method signature promises its callers.

You can add type constraints to `TResponse` to let you construct and initialize it, but that would exclude built-in types, such as `int`, from participating as `TResponse`:

```
interface IInitializable {
    void Initialize(object obj);
}
...
protected abstract TResponse Handle<TResponse>(T command) where TResponse : new, IInitializable;
...
protected override TResponse Handle<TResponse>(ListFilmsByIdCommand command) where TResponse : new, IInitializable {
    var res = new TResponse();
    res.Initialize(9);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a generic method, it means that the method can work with any type of object, which is clearly *not* the case here. Your method can only return an `int`. So remove your generics in the method signature.

Instead, make your abstract class generic:

```
class YourAbstractClass<T> {
    protected abstract T Handle(ListFilmsByIdCommand command);
}
```

Then, the concrete subclass can then do:

```
class ConcreteSubclass : YourAbstractClass<int> {
    protected abstract int Handle(ListFilmsByIdCommand command) {
        return 9;
    }
}
```